# Having trouble finding the greatest length of whitespace in string

Tags: python, string

I need to find the greatest length of white space in the string. No idea whats wrong.

```
def check1(x):
    cc = ()
    for i in x:
        if i != " ":
            lis.append(cc)
            cc=0
        else:
            cc +=1
            new.append(cc)
            print(cc)
```

I'm not sure whats wrong, its not adding to the appending list.

Answer (score 3):

Use `regex`es and builtin `max`:

```
import re
max_len = max(map(len, re.findall(' +', sentence)))
```

---

`re.findall(' +', sentence)` will find all the occurrences of one or more whitespaces.

`map(len, ...)` will transform this array into the array of the corresponding string lengths.

`max(...)` will get the highest value of these string lengths.

Comment: `max(re.findall('\s+', sentence), key=len)` would probably be better.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it brings back the longest string (sorted with `len` as key), and i assumed he wanted only spaces (excluding tabs etc.) so its better as `len(max(re.findall(' +', sentence), key=len))`

Comment: Yes; the idea is that this allows you to retrieve the stretch of whitespace in question while at the same time doing away with an unneeded function call.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'foo     bar       baz          lalala'
>>> max(len(list(v)) for is_sp, v in groupby(s, str.isspace) if is_sp)
10
```

The groupby will find consecutive runs of whitespace (`is_sp == True`) and consecutive runs of non-whitespace (`is_sp == False`).  In our case, we only care about the runs of whitespace, so we filter the non-whitespace cases away and then get the length of the consecutive runs.  Finally, the only thing that is left is to pick the largest of all of lengths.